# Do I need SSL certificate to send XML message to SAP PI?

Tags: xml, sap-pi, sap-xi

I'm creating an application that will POST an xml file to an SAP PI interface that was originally created for a legacy application. I have the endpoint URL as well as all the parameters such as; service, namespace, interface, qos.

I also have a username and password. Today I made my first test call to the DEV instance of SAP PI, and received and SSL cert error.

Is it correct that in order to POST to an SAP PI interface that my app needs an SSL cert?

Should what I am attempting work in theory, replicating the XML file and using the exact same interface as a legacy application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you will find SCN better for such questions.
http://scn.sap.com/community/pi-and-soa-middleware

But anyway, check the Basis person who administers the PI system.
There are a number of reasons why you might get a certificate error.

You may need to install a certificate on the sending system. The certificate on the PI system may have expired.  The PI system should have a detail log of what the CERT problem was.

You could also ask the admin to create and ENDPOINT that accepts on HTTP in Dev PI until the CERT issue is resolved assuming the  traffic is internal.

Comment: Thank You. Do you think my question can be asked as it is or is there additional information you recommend I include?

Comment: you are fine to ask. Im just suggesting the SAP dev community tends to hang on SCN more so than SO.